# How to shake virtual device created by Genymotion (Android Emulator)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, genymotion

I created a virtual device using Genymotion. I want to test an app that works with shaking the device. How can I make virtual device shake? I couldn't find how to shake that device.

Comment: Without using a USB-connected device for remote control?  That's the only way I know how to do it.

Answer (score 6):

**⌘+m** is working for OSX, Also Its working in Genymotion, for windows users willing to perform a shake gesture just use **Ctrl+m**

Comment: ctrl+m on windows

Answer (score 5):

> This method only work api under 15

For test accelerator and other like gravity,gyroscope,... can use this application.

First download [sensorsimulator](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/openintents/sensorsimulator-2.0-rc1.zip)

This is 2 application. One install(SensorSimulatorSettings-2.0-rc1.apk) in emulator second(sensorsimulator-2.0-rc1.jar) run in your PC.

[More info and full tutorial](http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-use-sensor-simulator-android-sdk-emulator)

[image]

Genymotion not support this feature :

[More info Genymotion Shell](https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/04_Tools/Genymotion_Shell/Genymotion_Shell.htm)

> Other way :

You can use Android Studio emulator Android 6.0(Google APIS) x86.

This this emulator(All x86/x64 bit) very fast and support all sensors.[image]

Like this:[image]

Comment: I installed apk to genymotion device and run both app and jar file. When i click Test Connect in sensorsimulator app, app freezes and makes device reboot.

Comment: Check install apk?

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a native way to emulate a shake in genymotion, but you could try a tool like [Frappe](https://github.com/niftylettuce/frappe) (Mac only) to send a shake action to the virtual device. Depending on the client you are trying to emulate, "adb shell input keyevent 82" may send a shake action, wake the device, or simulate a menu key press.

Comment: "adb shell input keyevent 82" opens the menu not shakes.

Comment: @cawwot Thanks. Works for me on ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

For Genymotion in particular for windows use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.